# What's the *proper* way to extract complex source code with tar?

Tags: linux, command-line, compression, symbolic-link, tar

Is there a standard way to use `tar` to decompress complex source code (such as in C or C++), in particular, which commonly includes symbolic links? The idea is to decompress it in a way that won't interfere with my compiling it. I don't have a problem when decompressing source code with a GUI-based tool, but I tend to get errors when I compile from source code extracted with such as this:

`tar xfzv sourceCode.tar.gz`

Do I need to do the following?

`tar xfzhv --keep-directory-symlink sourceCode.tar.gz`

And are symbolic links all I have to worry about here? What flag-equivalents do the GUI-based archive extractors tend to use? That would seem to be the standard most people seem to go by.

Source code has compile errors a lot of the time anyway, so I just want to be confident that I'm extracting it right and that the error wasn't the fault of the way I extracted it (sometimes it is and sometimes it isn't).

Comment: If you are the one creating the tar archive, you could use `-h` and `-c`, to causes tar to archive the files that the symbolic links point to, instead of the links themselves.

Comment: It depends on what the "GUI tool" does (they usually just set up and run the CLI command behind the scenes). And "complex source code" you get from e.g. SourceForge, GNU or other places won't include symlinks, at least not ones pointing to absolute (as opposed to local) places, so the first command should work fine (I've used that routinely for many years), from before there was Linux in fact).